# Ngx-leaflet tooltip close button redirect problem

Tags: leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I created markers from an array and added click event. I want to open tooltip when clicked a marker.

```
    let marker: any = L.marker(new L.LatLng(lat, lng));
    marker.on('click', (e) => {
        let target = e.target;
        if (!target._popup) {
            let content = 'content';
            target.bindPopup(content, {
                closeOnClick: false,
                closeButton: false,
                autoClose: true,
                closePopupOnClick: true
            }).openPopup();
        }
    });
```

When clicked the marker infowindow is opening. Here the problem is close button href attribute is redirecting page to #close. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/8159